# Java Write Log to Text

Tags: java, logging, instrumentation, javassist

Currently I'm instrumenting methods with loggers to trace some information but I have problem extracting the log output into the text file.

What I am doing is instrumenting every single method with `logger.info` but it doesn't work when you want to add handlers because that would be adding duplicate handlers for every method. I'm now using the `insertBefore()` method from Javassist for the instrumentation part, it goes something like this:

`insertBefore("Loggers and some implementations");` - this means that loggers/implementations are done in EVERY method before it is run, which means that if I were to add handlers here there will many as many handlers with the same name as the number of methods and duplicates give me errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't use you a single top-level handler? There is no need to define redundant handlers for lower level packages and methods, IMHO.

Maybe go through the manual and examples once more.